# I can't run any heroku cli commands - everything is completely unresponsive

Tags: heroku

I followed the directions to uninstall and then re-install Heroku here (homebrew instructions): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

And now whenever I type `heroku <anything>` everything simply hangs. I can't ctrl+break out or anything. Oddly enough, I can close the iTerm window without a warning that a process is running.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. No idea what exactly to do about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a ticket with Heroku yesterday about the same issue.

It turns out there is currently a bug in the `.netrc` parser. Try moving or removing the `~/.netrc` file on your local machine and then log back in. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Oh MAN - thank you! Feel like deleting that took a load off my shoulders.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I was going crazy for a while there myself. Nobody else in my org was affected, and meanwhile I couldn't even run `heroku --version`